# The loaded Image disappears after 1 second

Tags: java, android, lazy-loading, picasso

I'm attaching a `View` to my screen which contains an `ImageView` and uses Picasso to load the image from the server. It loads fine, but after a secong it disappears and is replaced with the placeholder.

I debugged the code to see if it has been recalled with an invalid URL, or if there's any other problem before it disappears. The function isn't called. It just disappears:

```
Picasso.with(activity)
                .load(showImageUrl)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .into(currentShowImage);
```

Why is this happening, and what can I do to prevent it from disappearing?

Comment: try opening that image in web browser

Comment: already did it's working fine on browser